# getting data from multiple csv files in linux

Tags: linux, csv

I'm attempting to select certain data from numerous csv files using linux, making a new file containing just the data I require for processing.

I have started by using grep and awk commands to select the rows and columns I require from a file.

I then wish to add a column which gives the filename as an entry for all rows.

Finally I want to repeat this for a number of files in a folder and append the results into one file. Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd just do it in a quick Perl script, personally. Loop in a file, spiit each line, and concat each column you want, plus the filename of the current file at the end of the line. Then loop over each file in the specified directory.

Comment: If you've already got the `awk` parts working (if you'd rather use another scripting language that's fine) for one file, you can use the shell `for f in *.csv; do ... done` or `find ... | while read f; do ... done` techniques to do many files; redirect the script output to get your one file out.

Comment: having `bash` and probably `awk` it far enough.

Comment: could you give me a quick example script so I can understand what you mean? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help?

grep gives you the filename of each file it finds a pattern.

You can pipe the output to sed and translate the ':' after each filename to a ',' as follows:

```
    grep FS *.awk  | sed 's/:/,/'
```

```
    empty.awk,BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
    join.awk,    OFS = sep = "\t"
    merge.awk,awk ' BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
    p11.awk,BEGIN { FS = "\t"   # make tab the field separator
    p42.awk,BEGIN                   { FS = OFS = "\t" }
    p43.awk,BEGIN   { FS = OFS = "\t" }
    p48.awk,BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
    p52.awk,BEGIN   { OFS = ":"; ORS = "\n\n" }
    p54.awk,BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
    smith.awk,BEGIN         { RS = ""; FS = "\n" }
```